# Rosjava build problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been working with rosjava and i had some troubles on instalation/build.I have been following the rosjava tutorial from the ros website and i got this error running the third instruction : ./gradlew test :

org.ros.time.NtpTimeProviderTest > testNtpUbuntuCom FAILED
java.lang.AssertionError at NtpTimeProviderTest.java:64

129 tests completed, 1 failed
:rosjava:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':rosjava:test'.

> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/eduardo/fuerte_workspace/rosjava_core-groovy-devel/rosjava/build/reports/tests/index.html

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 30.957 secs

If anyone could help with this will be gratefull
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62469/rosjava-build-problem/) by [edu7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4859/edu7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You installed the Groovy ROSjava version on Fuerte? Could be that that is the cause of the problem. There is no Fuerte version any more, but fortunately Martin Günther has made a fork, see here: http://answers.ros.org/question/65674/rosjava_core-in-fuerte/

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

same problem here
but no problem in generating Eclipse project files

---

Originally posted by [bbbExtremly](https://answers.ros.org/users/5281/bbbextremly/) with karma: 11 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1